# GCC, what does -&& mean on the command line?

Tags: bash, gcc

I execute a command like this

```
echo 'int main(){printf("%lu\n",sizeof(void));}' | gcc -xc  -w -&& ./a.out
```

and can get the result :1.
    but I can not find out what the -&& means,even after search man page and google!.and I try to execute it without the -&& option.it will be error like this:

```
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\317’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\372’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\355’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\376’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\7’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\16’ in program
./a.out:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\205’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\31’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\31’ in program
./a.out:1: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
```

......

Who knows the option means?

Comment: Some comments on your code: `sizeof (void)` is non-standard; it yields 1 due to a gcc-specific extension. The correct format for printing a `size_t` value is `%zu`. You need `#include <stdio.h>` before calling `printf` -- which means you'd need to echo two lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-&&` is interpreted by the shell not as a single token, but as two separate tokens: `-` and `&&`. The `-` token has no special meaning to the shell and is passed as an argument to `gcc`, which interprets it as an instruction to read the source from the standard input. `&&` is the shell operator that connects two commands in an *and* clause: `A && B` will execute `B` (`a.out`) only if `A` (`echo ... | gcc ...`) has finished successfully.

The point of using `gcc ... && ./a.out` instead of the simpler `gcc ...; ./a.out` is to run `a.out` only if the compilation has been successful, preventing a stale `a.out` from being executed.

Comment: it seems quite reasonable.could you tell me how do you know this,and I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: @user1242027 The `&&` operator is documented in the manual of your shell (`man bash` under "shell grammar"). It is also something you encounter often when reading other people's shell scripts. The `-` command-line parameter in the meaning of "read from standard input" is a long-time Unix tradition which you pick up by using various programs that follow it.